# Need two sidebar (right and left)in Twenty Seven theme

Tags: widgets, sidebar, content

I need two sidebars in Twenty Seven Theme. I created in Function.php, sidebar.php and index.php also. 
But both sidebars appearing on left. 
Please help me how to create exactly left and right...

Comment: Hello Tarun, you mean in Twenty Seven theme can not create left and right sidebar? Or I have to put "1) Lef Sidebar 2) Container 3) Right Sidebar" in CSS. If it is then where I have to put theme in CSS (like which paragraph between) Please tell me more details. I am not perfect at coding...

Answer (score 0):

For this you needs to three column

```
1) Lef Sidebar
2) Container
3) Right Sidebar
```

And then apply the CSS.